# Can we choose which parent to inherit from, in css?

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Is it possible to choose which parent an element to inherit from? For example, we have a normal HTML code with `<body>` tags and all that. Inside the `<body>` we have a `<header>` and `<div id="section">`, can we force the `#section` to inherit height from `<header>`?

Comment: Is `#section` immediately inside the `<header>` element? If so you can just do #section { height: inherit; }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused at what you are asking but I believe the answer is no.

Each tag in HTML has only one parent, since a parent is the object directly 'above' that tag in the hierarchy.

```
<section>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="section">
        <div id="A">
            <div id="B"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In this example, `#B`'s parent is `#A`. `#A`'s parent is `#section`.

To get the parent of a parent, this is best accomplished in `Javascript` or `JQuery`.

**Edit: Considering inheritance in CSS**

CSS inheritance is only done through the parent level directly above the tag, as described above. However, a multiple inheritance could be created.

`#section` could specify a font and this would be inherited by `#A`. In turn, this would be inherited by `#B` is the property is not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No you cannot select and modify a parent via css. There are some work arounds but your best interest is probably a jQuery approach or maybe a work around.

Check out this thread here:

[Hovering over SPAN needs to change background of DIV on same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871497/hovering-over-span-needs-to-change-background-of-div-on-same-level/26871757#26871757)

Comment: The problem is that for my class project, we are restricted to mostly CSS, JS and HTML. But I have to find another solution to my problem if I can't do it in CSS. Thanks though.

Comment: This isn't really what OP is asking. He's asking if we can choose for an element to inherit from a grandparent rather than a direct parent.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what the question is then, in this Explanation it seems like it goes `<html> -> <body> -> <header> -> <div id="section">` so it looks like the `#section` would inherit from header anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible in "pure CSS", but there are ways to achieve what you want quite easily :

- Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or other CSS pre-processor that allows you to inherit classes from elements that are not your parent, and a lot of other things. You could for example define your height in a varibale and use that for both the `header` and the `div`)
- Use jQuery to set the height of one element to the height of another
- Set your height in a class and apply that same class to both your `header`and your `<div>`